# action based on jquery cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I have a very simple 3 language website, I store the chosen language in cookies with jQuery.cookies. Each language text is stored in a div, and based on the retrieved language from cookies I display the chosen language (using jQuery show/hide).

For the 3 button selector, I display the clicked button as active with jQuery addClass.

I want to make the current language button active on refresh, by retrieving the information from the stored cookies.
But I can't find a way! Please Help! Thanks!

My cookies retrieval and show/hide function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var thechosenone = $.cookies.get( 'thechosenone' );
if($.cookies.get( 'thechosenone' ) == "newboxes1"|| $.cookies.get( 'thechosenone' ) == "newboxes2" || $.cookies.get( 'thechosenone' ) == "newboxes3") 
{ 
showonlyone(thechosenone);
}
          else {
var thechosenone = "newboxes1";
showonlyone(thechosenone);
}
});
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('div[name|="newboxes"]').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show();
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide();
          }
     });
$.cookies.set("thechosenone", thechosenone, { expires: 365 });    
}
```

My active button code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});   
});
```

My 3 buttons :

```
<a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');"  href="#" class="button" title="LANGUAGE 1"> LANGUAGE 1<br /></a>
<a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');"  href="#" class="button" title="LANGUAGE 2"> LANGUAGE 2<br /></a>
<a id="myHeader3" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes3');"  href="#" class="button" title="LANGUAGE 3">LANGUAGE 3<br /></a>
```

My text in Div :

```
<div name="newboxes" id="newboxes1">LANGUAGE 1 TEXT</div>
<div name="newboxes" id="newboxes2">LANGUAGE 2 TEXT</div>
<div name="newboxes" id="newboxes3">LANGUAGE 3 TEXT</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using addClass on document.ready?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
       var thechosenone = $.cookies.get( 'thechosenone' );
       if(!thechosenone ) thechosenone = "newboxes1";
       showonlyone(thechosenone);

       if(thechosenone=='newboxes1'){
         $("#myHeader1").addClass("active");
        } else  if(thechosenone=='newboxes2'){
         $("#myHeader2").addClass("active");
        } else if(thechosenone=='newboxes3'){
         $("#myHeader3").addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

I think it will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I used :

```
 $("myHeader1").addClass("active");
```

Instead of :

```
 $("#myHeader1").addClass("active");
```

I put your code in both loop and it works, thanks a lot ! :

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
var thechosenone = $.cookies.get( 'thechosenone' );
if($.cookies.get( 'thechosenone' ) == "newboxes1"|| $.cookies.get( 'thechosenone' ) == "newboxes2" || $.cookies.get( 'thechosenone' ) == "newboxes3") 
{ 
showonlyone(thechosenone);

   if(thechosenone=='newboxes1'){
         $("#myHeader1").addClass("active");
        } else  if(thechosenone=='newboxes2'){
         $("#myHeader2").addClass("active");
        } else if(thechosenone=='newboxes3'){
         $("#myHeader3").addClass("active");
        }

        }
          else {
var thechosenone = "newboxes1";
showonlyone(thechosenone);

   if(thechosenone=='newboxes1'){
         $("#myHeader1").addClass("active");
        } else  if(thechosenone=='newboxes2'){
         $("#myHeader2").addClass("active");
        } else if(thechosenone=='newboxes3'){
         $("#myHeader3").addClass("active");
        }

}
});
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('div[name|="newboxes"]').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).show();
          }
          else {
               $(this).hide();
          }
     });
$.cookies.set("thechosenone", thechosenone, { expires: 365 });    
}
</script>
```